# How to parse JSON File using Powershell, with conditions

Tags: json, powershell

I would like to work using powershell and json files.
I have a JSON file generated from an `Invoke-RestMethod` on Powershell.

The output json file look like :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "ID1",
        "isTemplate": true,
        "origin": "SPO_Promoteur_DEV",
        "tenant": "spo",
        "reference": "HbiuOzq1u",
        "date": "2019-02-04T16:01:35.230Z",
        "data":
        {
            "tasks":
            {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "parentId": "root",
                        "entities": [
                            "Something there"
                        ],
                        "Name": "A name there"
                    },
                    {
                        "parentId": "Z9zgsHzFad",
                        "entities": [
                            "urn:CodeEtape:DONGEN:CodeAction:TEST1"
                        ],
                        "Duration": 0,
                        "index": 0,
                        "Id": "wWotapvig"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "ID12",
        "isTemplate": true,
        "origin": "SPO_Promoteur_DEV",
        "tenant": "spo",
        "reference": "Hbkjh548u",
        "date": "2019-02-04T16:01:35.230Z",
        "data":
        {
            "tasks":
            {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "parentId": "root",
                        "entities": [
                            "Something else there"
                        ],
                        "Name": "An other name there"
                    },
                    {
                        "parentId": "Z9zgszffzfHzFad",
                        "entities": [
                            "urn:CodeEtape:DONGEN:CodeAction:TEST1"
                        ],
                        "Duration": 0,
                        "index": 0,
                        "Id": "wWotapvig"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to separate this json file.
How can i generate json files named `reference.json` (where reference is given on the json main file) AND having `isTemplate` as true ?

So i'll get X file, each of them having their reference as name, and each of them having the `IsTemplate` parameter to TRUE.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried using `Convertfrom-json` ?

Comment: `$LoginResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.json`
I Used this command just after the `Invoke-RestMethod` one.
I don't see the goal on converting to JSON and converting from JSON just after it ?
@RanadipDutta

Comment: You have gotten an answer which is pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can read in the json file, which contains an array of items and save each item as a separate new json file like below.

Each item gets a filename of `reference_XYZ.json` where 'XYZ' will be the '_id' value.

```
$inputFile  = 'FULL PATH TO YOUR INPUT JSON FILE'
$outputPath = Split-Path $inputFile -Parent
$json       = Get-Content -Raw -Path $inputFile | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($item in $json) {
    $fileName = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath ('reference_{0}.json' -f $item._id)
    $item | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File $fileName
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean with *and each of them having the IsTemplate parameter to TRUE*, since both items do have that property set to True..

If you mean to save only items that have this `"isTemplate": true` and ignore others that are false, just add a `Where-Object` clause to the `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ($item in ($json | Where-Object { $_.isTemplate -eq $true})) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this will help a lot. I'll work with this and let you know. Thanks for your answear.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for the edit. I mistakenly left the test variable name in there.

Comment: Can someone explain me why we'd use `$_.isTemplate -eq $true` instead of `$_.isTemplate -eq "true"` as the variable $true hasn't been defined in the code before ?

Comment: @MouAmg The `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet parses the json file into an object. (in fact an array of objects in this case). Wherever it encounters properties like `"isTemplate": true`, the value of this property is automatically converted to a Boolean value. In PowerShell you write a true boolean as `$true`. You can check by examining the type of the `isTemplate` property after conversion with something like this: `($json[0].isTemplate).gettype()`

Comment: Thanks you for the answears.
Just tested your code, exactly what i needed.
Thanks you once again. Solved.